# How to handle socket read in C when the remote server closes socket possibly before read is finished?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming, client-server

Client blocks on the read call waiting to read n bytes.

Server writes n bytes and closes the connection immediately.

Can read call return negative or zero in this case if the socket gets closed before read is finished or due to some other issue? (client/server running on same linux box in this case)

I am facing such a scenario but not sure how this works in TCP/IP subsystem and how to resolve it.

```
Sever:
write
close

Client:
read
close
```

Comment: What Joni said below.  Everyone should read the Ultimate SO_LINGER page ( http://blog.netherlabs.nl/articles/2009/01/18/the-ultimate-so_linger-page-or-why-is-my-tcp-not-reliable ) with regards to losing data on the close of a socket by the remote host.

Comment: The host to send the last message should do a half-close: shutdown(s, SHUT_WR) and then loop on calling recv() for a reasonable amount of time until it returns an error or 0 indicating that the remote host has either gone away or closed the connection.

Comment: Answers below probably solve your issue, but show us the `code` if you need more help!

Comment: 'The ultimate SO_LINGER page' is not a normative reference. The statement 'it often fails to do what we want - with the final kilobytes or sometimes megabytes of data transmitted never arriving' is simply untrue in my several decades of experience. 'When we issue a close() on a TCP/IP socket, depending on the circumstances, the kernel may do exactly that: close down the socket, and with it the TCP/IP connection that goes with it. And this does in fact happen - even though some of your data was still waiting to be sent' is completely incorrect: it is contrary to the specification in RFC 793.

Comment: not sure how long the server needs to wait on receive after sending shutdown because the server has other clients too and work. Dont want to block on the recv if the remote client is slow. The server is single threaded.

Comment: @selbie what is resonable amount of time? the server which sends a last message is also busy with other things and is a single threaded process. Also the client will only read data, it wont send anything to server

Comment: @Medicine If the receiver is reading it will block until data arrives, or until the read timeout expires if you've set one.

Answer (score 7):

The safe way to close a socket connection is first calling shutdown to signal that you won't be writing, keep reading the data that the remote side sends, and then shutdown the reading side and close the socket. If you close the socket before reading data sent to you the OS resets the connection (sends a packet with the RST flag set) and the remote side interprets this as an error.

Answer (score 4):

TCP treats the connection serially, and the reader processes everything in the order that the sender transmitted.  When the sender closes the connection, the reader will get an EOF after it has read all the data that was sent, not before.

Comment: Thanks. any reason why i might get a negative return value in this case. client/server running on same machine so I wouldn't assume socket is broken as its a quick query-response-close kind of application. It only happens once in a while, not every time. client tool sends a command. server sends reply and closes socket. client reads and closes socket.

Comment: A negative return from `read()` means there was an error. You should use `perror()` to see the error message.

Comment: perror printed - Connection reset by peer...I am sure the server has written data and closed socket. Client is in while loop blocked on select system call with a 1 sec timeout and trying to read data. How is this possible? This does not happen everytime for same use case.

Comment: 'Connection reset by peer' usually means you have written to a connection that has already been closed by the peer, as per @Joni's answer.