# Closing socket and handle in a client-server application

Tags: sockets, haskell, io, network-programming, handle

This question refers to the `Network` library in Haskell.

I have a simple client-server application. The server acquires a socket, accepts connections there, and forks a server thread to handle the requests:

```
sock <- listenOn port
(handle, _, _) <- accept socket
forkFinally (serve handle) (_ -> hClose handle)
-- Upon termination of the main thread I perform a 'sClose sock' as well
```

The client connects to the server, and reads and writes to the handle (as the server does):

```
handle <- connectTo host port
-- Read and write on 'handle'
```

Now my question is whether the client should close the handle as well when it finishes interacting with the server.

Secondly, the server thread terminates when an `"end"` string is received, but it sends a message `"bye"` before closing the handle. Looking at [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667901/how-to-handle-socket-read-in-c-when-the-remote-server-closes-socket-possibly-bef), it seems closing the handle at the server still allows the client to read all the data sent to it. My tests confirm this, but maybe I got just lucky. Will closing the handle at the server allow the client to read the data in all cases?

Comment: Yes, if any of the two sides doesn't want to read from the socket again, it can write its final data and the close the socket. The other side will still be able to read all that final data.

Comment: And I guess the best practice is to close the handle at both ends, isn't it?